# Numpy, rounding the value of a polinomial function gives different results

Tags: python, numpy

I'm experiencing some weird behavior when using a polynomial fit. When I round the result of a ***np.poly1d*** object call I get a different result than if I would round that number specifically. Down you can see the code sample I am having issues with. In the center_power assignment, the ***p(center_angle)*** call returns -0.0, and rounded up that should be 0 and it is, if I go in the reple and do ***round(-0.0, 5)*** I get the return 0. However, when the call **round(p(center_angle), 5)** gets executed, that evaluates to -0.25974.

Any explanation to why this weird behavior?

[image]

```
angles = np.linspace(-10, 10, 21)
el = np.zeros(21,)
power = np.concatenate((np.linspace(-10, 0, 11),
                         np.linspace(-1, -10, 10)))

    poly = fit_polynomial(power, angles, 3)

p = np.poly1d(poly)
q = p.deriv() #Get the derivative
roots = np.roots(q) #Roots of derivative indicate where reaches 0 and power is max

#Get center point
center_angle = round(roots[-1].real, 5)

#This is where the center_power is different than what I expect
center_power = round(p(center_angle), 5)


def fit_polynomial(power: List[float], angles: List[float], bandwidth: float):

    index, max_value = _get_index_and_value_of_max(power)
    if index == 0 or index == len(power)-1 :
         raise ValueError("Power peak detected at edge of main beam segment.")

    #because python does slicing by item cound instead of index
    split_count = index+1
    left_half = power[:split_count]
    right_half = power[split_count:]

    side_range = max_value - bandwidth
    left_point = _closest(left_half, side_range)
    right_point = _closest(right_half, side_range)

    #Subset data at cutoff distance left and right of the max power value
    signal_subset = power[left_point[0]:len(left_half)+right_point[0]+1]
    positions_subset = angles[left_point[0]: len(left_half)+right_point[0]+1]
    z = np.polyfit(positions_subset, signal_subset, 4)
    return z
```

Comment: Could you give the coefficients of poly?

Comment: Just edited the fit_polynomial call. The bandwidth value is not the poly exponent. That is specified lower as being 4.

Comment: When inspecting the type of the p(center_angle) return, it seems that it's a numpy.float64 that returns the weird rounding value. If I do round of a normal float I get the expected result.

Comment: Have you tried this outside the debugger?

Comment: Yes, the problem I noticed when I was writing the test function for it. And then replicated it with the debugger.